# Doing a complex 2D transformation

Tags: rotations, transformation, geometric-transformation

Given the following graphical representation of shape that has been transformed:

[image: Transformation]

What is the final transformation matrix for it?

**I am doing the following:**

Translate center to origin:
$ T_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -0.5 \\
0 & 1 & -0.5 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}  $

Scale : $S = \begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}  $

Then some kind of rotation should occur after : $R=?$

Then finally another translation to the point $M=(4,5)$ : $ T_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}  $

Any ideas what's the easiest approach to figure out $R$ ?

Comment: The lengths in the figure on the right do not appear to be to scale, and I can't figure out what the angles say (not that it would help much if I could; too few angles are marked). All we really need to know is the coordinates of the point on the right-hand figure where the two tails of the arrows meet and the coordinates of the two points at the tips of the arrows; I just don't see enough information to deduce those coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Let's forget the translation first and consider the figure where the transformed house has its lower-left corner at the origin.

You can represent $v_x'$ using polar coordinates:

$$v_x' = \begin{bmatrix} R\cos(\theta) \\ R\sin(\theta) \end{bmatrix}$$

where $\theta$ is the angle of rotation and $R$ the scaling factor. From the figure $R=4$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$. Therefore, $v_x'=\begin{bmatrix} 2\sqrt{2}\\ 2\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}$.

Now, $v_y'$ is vertical, so $v_y'=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ h \end{bmatrix}$ for some real number $h$. Using the right triangle in the figure with side $5$ and taking $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$, we got $h=5\sqrt{2}$. Therefore, $v_y'=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 5\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}$.

This means that the linear transformation (without the translation) is

$$\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} 2\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 2\sqrt{2} & 5\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$

Finally, the translation sends $\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ onto $\begin{bmatrix} 4-\sqrt{2}\\ 5-\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{2}\end{bmatrix}$ so can be represented by the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 4-\sqrt{2}\\ 5-\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{2}\end{bmatrix}$ and the transformation you are looking for is

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix} \mapsto 
\begin{bmatrix} 4-\sqrt{2}\\ 5-\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{2}\end{bmatrix} +
\begin{bmatrix} 2\sqrt{2} & 0 \\ 2\sqrt{2} & 5\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 4-\sqrt{2} + 2x\sqrt{2}  \\ 5-\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{2} + 2x\sqrt{2} + 5y\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: `You are looking for a transformation in the plane, so a 3×3 matrix is not suitable`, Isn't it trivial that the coordinates are homogeneous?

Comment: The use of a $3\times3$ matrix for an affine transformation in the plane is a convention at least in computer graphics. The bottom row of the matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: @DavidK: OK, you're right. But there is nothing wrong with my answer.

Comment: We've only been arguing about the first sentence. A more serious question is, do you really think that this transformation maps $(0,0)$ to $(7/2,9/2)$?

Comment: @JohnC. I would recommend you study the $2\times2$ matrix in this answer; it is a much more useful step than the diagonal submatrix with $4$ and $5$ on the diagonal.